# Symfony Console Table: how to center columns content?

Tags: php, symfony, console-application, text-alignment

Using [Table](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/console/helpers/table.html) of [Symfony Console Component](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/console.html) one can draw tables with rows and columns.

How to align to the center the content of the columns?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to change the style of a Table, one should use the [TableStyle](http://api.symfony.com/current/Symfony/Component/Console/Helper/TableStyle.html) class and its [setPadType](http://api.symfony.com/3.2/Symfony/Component/Console/Helper/TableStyle.html#method_setPadType) method passing `STR_PAD_BOTH` to it.

Example:

```
$table = new Table($output);

// set table contents
// ...

$tableStyle = new TableStyle();
$tableStyle->setPadType(STR_PAD_BOTH);

$table->setStyle($tableStyle)->render();
```